# Azure devops error: Git checkout failed with exit code: 1

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, azure-repos

I have pushed code from my local machine to azure repos. While pushing code that time head was pointing to Master branch. Which is ok. After that i created release and found 'git checkout error'. I checked agent machine and i could see here it head pointing to particular commit not a branch. How i can solve this issue?

See logs here,

```
2020-02-04T07:34:23.2688328Z You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
2020-02-04T07:34:23.2688360Z changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
2020-02-04T07:34:23.2688390Z state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
2020-02-04T07:34:23.2688437Z 
2020-02-04T07:34:23.2688466Z If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
2020-02-04T07:34:23.2688496Z do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
2020-02-04T07:34:23.2688518Z 
2020-02-04T07:34:23.2688565Z   git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
2020-02-04T07:34:23.2688588Z 
2020-02-04T07:34:23.2688616Z HEAD is now at 5c95b07 Added samplefile
2020-02-04T07:34:23.3208965Z An error occurred during download: System.InvalidOperationException: Git checkout failed with exit code: 1
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.TfsGitArtifact.DownloadAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ArtifactDefinition artifactDefinition, String downloadFolderPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.<>c__DisplayClass39_2.<<DownloadArtifacts>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.RetryExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Func`1 action)
2020-02-04T07:34:23.3209166Z Retrying download...
2020-02-04T07:34:23.3211433Z Ensuring artifact folder C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.163.1\_work\r2\a\_JHipsterDemoRepo exists and is clean.
2020-02-04T07:34:26.6696074Z Syncing repository: 3290da05-8551-4d0f-a00c-037d882d4835 (Git)
2020-02-04T07:34:26.6699057Z Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'git.exe'.
2020-02-04T07:34:26.6700464Z ##[command]git version
2020-02-04T07:34:26.6934186Z git version 2.21.0.windows.1
2020-02-04T07:34:26.6962266Z ##[command]git init "C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.163.1\_work\r2\a\_JHipsterDemoRepo"
2020-02-04T07:34:26.7597056Z Initialized empty Git repository in C:/agent/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.163.1/_work/r2/a/_JHipsterDemoRepo/.git/
2020-02-04T07:34:26.7621586Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://218316@dev.azure.com/218316/CITS-Insights%20POC/_git/JHipsterDemoRepo
2020-02-04T07:34:26.7846491Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2020-02-04T07:34:26.8167913Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://218316@dev.azure.com/218316/CITS-Insights%20POC/_git/JHipsterDemoRepo.extraheader
2020-02-04T07:34:26.8372843Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2020-02-04T07:34:26.8590568Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-02-04T07:34:26.9953230Z remote: Azure Repos        
2020-02-04T07:34:26.9953340Z remote: We noticed you're using an older version of Git. For the best experience, upgrade to a newer version.
```

Comment: its not an issue, azure devops always checks out that way

Comment: Will you please suggest me how i can resolve this 'Git checkout failed error' Because i am not able to find out the root cause

Comment: well, thats too random. anything can be behind this

Comment: We'll need more details to help fix that. Have you performed a build with diagnostics turned on? Can you attach that log here?

Comment: Please find logs. FYI i am using git version 2.25.0

Answer (score 2):

> Azure devops error: Git checkout failed with exit code: 1

According to the error log:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceAsync
```

Then I check the corresponding source function code: [GetSourceAsync](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/src/Agent.Plugins/GitSourceProvider.cs#L220). It seems your repos has sub module, so this issue may caused by did not enable `Checkout Submodule` optional before build.

The default value of `checkoutSubmodules` is `False`.

To resolve this issue, try go `Add an artifact` page, then enable the optional: `Checkout submodules`:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried checking 'checkout sub module' but its not working. Getting same error.

Comment: @SurajShinde, How about using the hosted agent instead of your private agent? If this issue not occurred on the hosted agent, please try to share the debug log in your question.